# Type.GetInterfaces() workaround for .NET Standard 1.x

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-standard

`.NET Core 1.1` supports `Type.GetInterfaces()` method which provides a list of the interfaces implemented on a given type.  Unfortunately, `Type.GetInterfaces()` is not yet available in `.NET Standard 1.x`.

The good news is that it is supposed to included in `.NET Standard 2.0`.

In the meantime, does anyone know of a workaround I can use to get the list of interfaces on a type and/or the list of classes which implement a given interface in `.NET Standard 1.x`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick.  `GetTypeInfo()` is an extension method in the `System.Reflection` namespace, part of the `InstrospectionExtensions`.

```
using System.Reflection;
var interfaces = typeof({SOME_TYPE}).GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces();
```

Comment: I believe GetInterfaces() is not implemented in .NET Standard 1.x.  Am I incorrect in that understanding?

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin `Type.GetInterfaces()` is not, but `TypeInfo.GetInterfaces()` is.  The code is just using the extension method to access a `TypeInfo` of the `Type` using the `GetTypeInfo()` extension method.  This worked for me using a `.NET Standard 1.6` library and a `.NETCoreApp1.1` console app.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Roberto, that works like a charm. Thank you so very much! :)

Comment: Note that the extensions are available for .NET Standard 1.x by installing the [`System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/). Working on .NET Standard 1.3 for me.